# Prevent OS X 10.8 from going to sleep

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I need to stop OS X from running screensaver for a while, and then allow it. I found IOKit's functions IOPMAssertionCreateWithName and IOPMAssertionRelease, but they don't work as expected. After creating Assertion, screensaver is blocked, it's ok, but it is still blocked even after I release my Assertion. Here is some sample code I have on github: https://github.com/silvansky/OSX-TestSleep - the main method is like this:

```
- (IBAction)toggle:(id)sender
{
    if (_assertionID == kIOPMNullAssertionID)
    {
        // toggle on
        CFStringRef reasonForActivity= CFSTR("Test reason");

        IOReturn success = IOPMAssertionCreateWithName(kIOPMAssertionTypePreventUserIdleDisplaySleep, kIOPMAssertionLevelOn, reasonForActivity, &_assertionID);
        [self.statusField setStringValue:@"Assert ON"];
        NSLog(@"*** lock: %d, success: %d", _assertionID, success);
    }
    else
    {
        // toggle off
        IOReturn success = IOPMAssertionRelease(_assertionID);
        [self.statusField setStringValue:@"Assert OFF"];
        NSLog(@"*** unlock: %d. success: %d", _assertionID, success);
        _assertionID = kIOPMNullAssertionID;
    }
}
```

So, when I press "toggle" button second time, screensaver is still blocked.

Is there a way to fix that? My system is OS X 10.8.2, Xcode 4.5.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I found an explanation of such behavior.

OS X just added an assertion for powerd (with timeout 300 secs) process after I release my assertion. So, screensaver starts in 5-6 minutes after I allow it, not after 1 minute (as I set in System Preferences). I really don't know why.

I have updated my source on github, so it prints out all assertions on toggle action.

This strange behavior of OS X, as some people say, appeared in 10.8.